# Executing SSIS Package from File System

Tags: sql-server, ssis, amazon-rds, dtexec

We execute SSIS package using below command written in a batch file. (On premises MSSQL DB)
D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC.exe>" "E:\Packages\SSISPKG1.dtsx" /Config "E:\Packages\Config\config.dtsConfig".

Now we migrate to AWS RDS-MSSQL service. How to execute .dtsx file stored in S3 bucket.
**What is the path of DTEXEC.exe for RDS - MSSQL. (Microsoft SQL Server)?**

As I am assuming, RDS-MSSQL Service create an hidden EC2 instance for processing and storing data. **Is it possible to create a folder on that instance to keep .dtsx file and run a batch file when needed?**

Comment: Knowing nothing of amazon-rds but I did read Piotr's link only answer. I would _presume_ you can enable `xp_cmdshell` If that's the case, then you can use the SQL Server system properties to find the sql server install location and then look for `DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe` off that path

Answer (score 0):

RDS supports only project deployment mode. There is a tutorial:
[Using Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services on Amazon RDS for SQL Server](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-microsoft-sql-server-integration-services-on-amazon-rds-for-sql-server/)